# iconv php dotless i (ı)

Tags: php, mysql, iconv

I am using iconv to convert Turkish letters into standard latin-1. The other non-standard letters are being replaced correctly (C for Ç etc.) For some reason I am having no luck in changing a dotless i into a dotted i. Instead ? is shown instead of ı. So Çocuk Yogası should read as Cocuk Yogasi.

Here is what I have

```
$egitname = $result->header;
$imgname = $result->heading;
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $egitname);
```

I have tried using ISO instead of ASCII, which isn't any help and I'm really at a loss as to why it isn't working. Perhaps there is something I've overlooked.